# Too many inner classes?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I learned that inner classes are to be used when an object is closely associated with another object. So a LinkedList class might contain an inner Node class, since each Node exists only in its LinkedList.

I'm thinking about making a game, and am considering making a Map object, with a double array of Tiles, where each Tile is an inner class.

But then I thought that really, the Map class should be an inner class inside the Game class.

Thus we have

```
class Game {
  class Map {
    Tile[][] grid;
    class Tile {
      ...
    }
  ...
  }
  class Unit {
    ...
  }
  class Player {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

However, this seems excessive, since it results in just one, massive file. Is this a problem? Or am I completely misunderstanding the point of inner classes?

What are the factors one should consider when choosing to make your new class inner or outer and, if the choice is inner, when should the inner class be `static`?

Comment: It's better to think of your program as a series of outer classes, with the occasional inner class being a rare exception.  I've gone my whole career without ever having to write a single inner class.

Comment: id go with @RobertHarvey and have the same experience

Comment: There are going to be a lot of opinions about this, but I typically keep my inner classes down to the objects that are only used within the context of the containing class. If I have a need for it elsewhere, from some other context, it becomes its own class.

Comment: Maybe you should look into using packages instead of classes to hold a group of related classes.

Comment: You might want to [take a look at the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/whentouse.html)

Comment: This question is somewhat subjective; please see [stackoverflow.com/dont-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/classes-and-interfaces/ch04lev1sec10

Comment: From a pragmatic standpoint, inner classes must be coded in the same file as the corresponding outer class.  Too many inner classes results in very large source files.  In addition, it becomes impossible to use subdirectories to group similar components together.  Like Mr Harvey, I've never coded an (explicit) inner class "in anger".

Comment: This question is subjective, but I feel it meets the "constructive" criteria. Voting to reopen.

Comment: This design achieves **encapsulation** - one of the fundamental benefits of object oriented design. Unfortunately it falls short of the **decoupling** that is often considered the second primary benefit. It is, however, easy to refactor into a fully decoupled design so is a good - though perhaps infantile - design. Voting for reopen with a suggestion to move to `Programming` or elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When to use inner classes is as much art as it is science. Basically look at how big your code file is getting and how big each class is. If a class is big and complicated it should probably go in its own file. If it's small (for example a single function implementation of a listener interface) and unlikely to be re-used elsewhere then it should probably be an inner class.

In fact re-use is probably one of the most important criteria. Anything that can be re-used should be re-used and should be scoped appropriately to enable that.

An important advantage of inner classes is that they can help with encapsulation, keeping the internal implementation of your class internal. If other classes do not need to know about your inner classes (or in some cases even that they exist) then that is an excellent reason for them to be inner.

Comment: I would qualify that as "if it's small, and very unlikely to be used anywhere else but inside the class in which it is written."

Answer (score 1):

It's not a question of 'too many', at least not until you hit some hard limit. It's a question of what can reasonably be said to belong inside what. A Map will always have Entries, which can be an inner class. A Game won't always have have a Map, so the Map shouldn't be inner to Game.

Answer (score 1):

The question I would ask is 'Does the inner class make sense as a concept unto itself?' Does an object of type `Map` have meaning, or does `Game.Map` add significant value?

I would `Map` makes sense on its own, and should therefore be an outer class. You can then specify the close relationship of Game and Map using namespaces.

Comment: I'm not sure Map really makes sense on its own, since the behavior of a map depends a lot on which game it comes from. Chess.Board is very different from Monopoly.Board.

Comment: But you could write a Map-editing program for your Game, in which case you would need the Map class separate from the Game class. The Board classes for Chess and Monopoly are not, typically, only distinguished by perhaps being inner classes of Chess and Monopoly, but also by being in packages com.example.game.chess and com.example.game.monopoly.

Comment: @Ypnypn Neither Chess nor Monopoly would likely make sense as a class. They would be a namespace with several classes, such as Chess.Game and Chess.Board.

Answer (score 0):

In the game example that you are trying to implement, y. Map and tiles can be an appropriate data structure rather then separate inner classes.  Any specific requirements of having them as classes?

Answer (score -4):

At my own opinion, inner class are just useless and lead to bad design, using access that should not be granted, making the code unclear.
Just forgot about it.

(At my own opinion, of course)

Comment: There are many situations in which you would want your code to have implicit access to the containing objects methods and fields. This more than justifies knowing how and when to use inner classes.

Comment: This is definitely not true. Inner classes can be very *good* design if used appropriately. In fact, they are used many times in the standard JDK classes.

Comment: Actually, though crudely stated there is a fair amount of truth to what you say.  First off, inner classes are crudely implemented (no real JVM support, eg) and hence have significant restrictions and oddities about them.  And they do, as often as not, make the code less clear.